# Cant view php errors on elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

No matter what I do I cant get php errors to show on elastic beanstalk.

I put error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); at the start of the script.

and error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = On in php.ini and still nothing.

I cant debug the problem on my local machine as its only happening in elastic beanstalk.

Any ideas.

Comment: Maybe you use `@` before your functions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS team response to [Problems with PHP APC cache running out of memory](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=330844#330844), they are *not limiting anything intentionally* and *simply installed stock PHP and stock APC* on [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/):

> Elastic Beanstalk is geared toward professional-grade developers whom
>   we prefer to treat as adults. We're pretty laissez faire about what
>   you want to do with your environments.

However, I wouldn't be surprised if industry/security best practices are applied regardless, i.e. limiting the altering of respective settings in PHP scripts and/or Apache `.htaccess` files by default at least, and [mcfritzn's response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=331115#331115) hints towards this as well:

> My observations
>
> - ini_set() can NOT be used to influence apc.shm_size and apc.ttl
> - the configuration can be controlled by accessing the EC2 instance, edit '/etc/php.d/apc.ini' and reboot Apache using 'sudo
>     /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful'
> - [...]

Accordingly, I suggest you review and alter the Apache/PHP server settings on the instance itself, which should provide respective insights (and potentially a solution on the side).